# Copy pattern text from one file to another file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a csv file with the below text as variable value after each "=". I want to take the value of each variable and replace it another file which has the exact same variable names with a prefix "$$".

Both the files are in the Linux box and I am trying to use sed/awk for shell scripting but struggling to get thru.

### file_1.csv

```
MIN_FISCAL_PERIOD=DEC_FY_20

MAX_FISCAL_PERIOD=APR_FY_20

MIN_CALENDAR_DATE=12/01/2019

MAX_CALENDAR_DATE=04/01/2020
```

### file_2_to_replace.prm

```
$$PI_MIN_CALENDAR_DATE=01/01/2018

$$PI_MAX_CALENDAR_DATE=12/01/2019

$$PI_MIN_FISCAL_PERIOD=NULL

$$PI_MAX_FISCAL_PERIOD=NULL
```

In the above example, the values for each variable from file_1.csv should be copied and replaced to appropriate variable in the file_2_to_replace.prm.

Comment: Are the corresponding line numbers in each file constant, or variable?  As in, does line 2 and greater in one file, match in the other?  If so, this is doable.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].  SO is not a code writing service, but we can help.  Please show us the code you tried, how it fails, ...  And please do research.  Most questions have already been answered.  That being said, this is doable.  One detail that will make it somewhat more difficult is the use of `$` since this means something to the bash.

Comment: The second file is a parameter file which will be used for Informatica Workflows. It will have other parameters required for the Workflows. Like i mentioned, I want to read the  variable name from the 1st file and replace the values in the .prm file for corresponding variables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming as I asked earlier, that the line numbers match, this is a simple cut and paste.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat file_2_to_replace.prm | cut -d'=' -f1 > temp
cat file_1.csv | cut -d'=' -f2 > temp2
paste -d'=' temp temp2 | sed s'/^=$//' > file_2_to_replace.prm
```

Comment: The line numbers dont match in the .prm file. The fist .csv file where the 4 variable values copied from have same line numbers, but the .prm file where the variable values should be copied will have lot more other parameters too as it is used for Informatica Workflows.

Comment: Unless you have a boss who is demanding that you stick to CSV, I would strongly encourage you to switch to SQL, and then use a scripting language like PHP or Python which has dedicated APIs for working with it.

The shell utilities are designed for working with flat text; unless you structure things very carefully, they don't do relation well.

Comment: If i can get the value "DEC_FY_20" for the line MIN_FISCAL_PERIOD=DEC_FY_20, then i can manage to replace in the 2nd file. Like wise, if i can get the value for each line based on keywords like "MIN_FISCAL_PERIOD" or "MAX_FISCAL_PERIOD", i can manage to replace the values to the other file